# Копирование снимка с камеры

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Пытаюсь написать приложение которое, находясь в фоновом режиме, копировало бы в свою папку фото, сделанные штатным приложением и потом обрабатывало его. Технический вопрос именно по части копирования: возможно ли в принципе сделать копирование из фонового режима. Если да, то какие методы ковырять?

Comment: Что подразумевается под фоновым режимом? Какой-то бекграунд поток? Сервис?

Comment: Сервисы вам прекрасно помогут. Но нужно следить за флагами сна. http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/157-urok-92-service-prostoj-primer.html

Comment: Интересует сервис

Comment: Подскажите методы, пожалуйста!